# How do I write reusable method/actions in Codeception?

Tags: php, testing, codeception, web-api-testing

I am writing a set of API tests using Codeception and one of the methods I would like to have on every single test looks like:

```
public function ActionWasNotDoneIfParamsAreMissing(ApiTester $I): void
{
    $url = $this->serviceUrl;
    $method = $this->method;

    $dataCombination = $I->pcArrayPowerSet($this->data);
    foreach ($dataCombination as $combination) {
        $I->seeExceptionThrown(
            BadRequestHttpException::class,
            static function () use ($I, $url, $combination) {
                $I->$method($url, $combination);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

I did read docs [here](https://codeception.com/docs/06-ReusingTestCode) and [here](https://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage) but is not so clear to me how to achieve re-usability in this scenario.

I wonder if there is a way to add this as part of a Helper so it can be reuse at any single test without the need to repeat the code. Any ideas and/or help?

Answer (score 1):

I have got my answer [here](https://codeception.com/docs/06-ReusingTestCode). Here are the steps I have followed:

- Create the `StepObject` class by running the command:

  ```
  php vendor/bin/codecept generate:stepobject api CommonTest
  ```
- Adjust the method as follow:

  ```
  public function checkIfHttpMethodIsNotAccepted(
      string $serviceUrl,
      array $notAllowedMethod = [],
      array $data = []
  ): void {
      $I = $this;
      foreach ($notAllowedMethod as $method) {
          $I->seeExceptionThrown(
              BadRequestHttpException::class,
              static function () use ($I, $serviceUrl, $method, $data) {
                  $I->$method($serviceUrl, $data);
              }
          );
      }
  }
  ```
- Call the new method from the test class:

  ```
  public function ActionWasNotDoneIfHttpMethodIsNotAccepted(Step\Api\CommonTest $I): void
  {
      $I->checkIfHttpMethodIsNotAccepted(
          $this->serviceUrl, 
          self::$notAllowedMethod, 
          $this->data
      );
  }
  ```

From now on I just have to do the last on my test classes and not repeat the code all over the places. Hope it help someone!

> **Note:** If for some reason you got errors run the command `php vendor/bin/codecept build` before run any test suite.